# Twoside documentclass: Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, double-sided, badness

I'm using the documentclass `article` with the option `twoside` in order to customize the header and the footer for even and odd pages with the `fancyhdr` package. The compilation works, but the problem is that the output panel gives me the following badbox:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

I think the problem is due to the use of the `geometry` package, but I don't know how to solve it. What does it mean and how can I get rid of it? This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={120mm,195mm},top=2.7cm,bottom=2.7cm,right=1.3cm,left=1.3cm]{geometry}%left1.6
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{Titolo}
\fancyhead[CE]{Autore}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Comment: you have not provided a usable example, so it is hard to help, but perhaps add `heightrounded` to the geometry options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the page size allows a full page of lines of text (which has no vertical flexibility) fit into `\textheight` The `heightrounded` option tells geometry to ensure this constraint is met.